# design a style using tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

How can I use latex tikz package to design the style that is seen in the picture?[image]

Comment: Such a huge package as tikz is not really necessary for this style.

Comment: what is your advice in this manner. I do not need to use memoir class.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using  `titlesec` , `xcolor`, `colortbl`, `geometry` and `lettrine` (this last one only for my pleasure…). I was unsure whether the light blue  background was also required, so there's none in my code, but that can be changed:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage{garamondx}%%
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tabularx, colortbl}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}%
    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\fontfamily{EBGaramondInitials-TLF}\color{titlecolour}}

    \colorlet{titlecolour}{Cyan4!85!}
    \newlength\labelframewd
    \settowidth{\labelframewd}{\lsstyle\scshape\small\MakeLowercase{\chaptername}}

    \newsavebox\chaplabelbox%

    \newcommand\chaplabel{\color{titlecolour}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c@{\enspace}X}
        \lsstyle\scshape\small\MakeLowercase{\chaptername}\\
        \cellcolor{titlecolour}\raisebox{-1ex}[5ex][20ex]{\color{black}\bfseries\fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\thechapter} & \titlerule[3pt]
        \end{tabularx}
    }%

    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering}
    {\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} \smash{\chaplabel}}%
    {2ex}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}\vskip-10ex\hskip\labelframewd\fontsize{28}{32}\selectfont\bfseries}%

    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{10\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand*\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Tweedledee \& Tweedledum}

    \lettrine{T}{ext} text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I applied your code, the word "CHAPTER", that is above the chapter number, does not appear. would you please help in this?

Comment: ??? I suppose you inserted my proposed code inside a code of yours. Could I have a minimal (non-)working example. Also, just to test, in the definition of the label, replace the line: `\lsstyle\scshape\small\MakeLowercase{\chaptername}\\ ` with the simpler `\small\textsc{chapter}\\ `.

Comment: No, really I run your code as it. The same problem when I modified your suggestion.

Comment: That seems to be tough! Would you test: 1) not loading the fonts (i.e. sticking to the default Computer Modern) *and* 2) adding something like `\color{red}`just before `chapter`(or `\chaptername`). I suspect that, for some reason, the word ‘chapter’ could be *inside*  the frame, and of the same colour.

Comment: Unfortunaly, the same problem. The modified code is

Comment: I really don't see… Everything else is here, only the word ‘chapter’ is missing? Did you look at the .log file to see any warnings? Do you have *exactly* the same preamble?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem. please see the modified code in the answers.