# Titlesec, space between header and chapter style

Tags: titlesec

I tried to adapt @Bernard [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198661/design-a-style-using-tikz-package/198687#198687) to my case, but I am facing some troubles. It is possible that I just simply don't understand the code, but I tried to change almost every parameters, and I can't solve it

Here is a MWE, well not so minimal, but adapted to what I need :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpagestyle{fancy}[\small\scshape]{\headrule
\sethead{The nice header}{}{\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{}{\usepage}
}

\colorlet{titlecolour}{Aquamarine3}
\newlength\labelframewd
\settowidth{\labelframewd}{\lsstyle\scshape\small\MakeLowercase{\chaptername}}

\newsavebox\chaplabelbox%

\newcommand\chaplabel{\color{titlecolour}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c@{\enspace}X}
    \cellcolor{titlecolour}\raisebox{-1ex}[2ex][7ex]{\hspace{1cm}} & \vskip-5.3mm\titlerule[2pt]
    \end{tabularx}
    }%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\flushleft}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} \smash{\chaplabel}}%
{1ex} %position titre
{\thispagestyle{fancy}\vskip-11ex\hskip\labelframewd\fontsize{28}{32}\selectfont\bfseries}%

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{\flushleft}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} \smash{\chaplabel}}%
{1ex} %position titre
{\thispagestyle{fancy}\vskip-11ex\hskip\labelframewd\fontsize{28}{32}\selectfont\bfseries}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Nice Chapter}
\lipsum[0-2]
\newpage
\lipsum[0-2]
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

The output :

[image]

EDIT : I did not had problems when I used the chapterstyle as it was. It's when I tried to change the blue(green?) box size that it appeared.

Comment: try to replace `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{1\baselineskip}` with something like `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}`

Comment: It's only worse ! It add more space between the chapter and the header

Comment: i will try to add an answer later

Comment: I identified one problem, it comes from the {c@{\enspace}X}. If I replace with {c@{\vspace{y}}X}, I can control (with y) the spacing between header and chapter head, but I lose the spacing between the ruler and the box

Comment: SOLVED : {c@{\vspace{1.5cm}\enspace}X} and I get to control the spacing by modifying the vspace !

Comment: Do you want to write a self answer:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB : Adding of the solution found 2 years ago but only posted in comments (as I could not give answer to my own questions then)
SOLVED IT : {c@{\vspace{1.5cm}\enspace}X} and I get to control the spacing by modifying the vspace !